# How can I get the images to stay on a specific row when using a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm trying to do this responsive image grid (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp), but instead of having four columns on one row, I have three columns and the fourth one jumps to the next row. See picture: [3 columns instead of 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdYCi.jpg)

When resizing the window, instead of having 2 columns on one row, I have one. See picture: [1 column instead of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPU37.jpg)

What could be the problem?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="./japan1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan3.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="./japan1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="./japan3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="./japan2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./japan1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.row {
width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column{
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;

}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: It still looks the same, I don't understand the problem.. :(